# What is the proof-theoretic ordinal of true arithmetic?

Tags: logic, ordinals, foundations, proof-theory, ordinal-analysis

The proof theoretic ordinal of $PA$ is $\epsilon_0$.  My question is, what is the proof-theoretic ordinal of true arithmetic, i.e. $Th(\mathbb{N})$?

I’m assuming you get something bigger than $\epsilon_0$ and smaller than $\Gamma_0$, the Feferman-Schutte ordinal which is significantly less than $\omega_1^{CK}$.  I say this because Feferman and Schutte constructed infinitary deductive systems for ramified second-order arithmetic which included the omega-rule, and those systems had proof-theoretic ordinal $\Gamma_0$.  And true arithmetic is obtained by adding the omega-rule to $PA$.

Would it be cleaner to ask what the proof-theoretic ordinal of $ACA_0$ plus the omega rule is, since you can then speak more explicitly about a relation being a well-order?

Answer (score 7):

This isn't really a question that makes sense. Let me illustrate this with two common interpretations of the term:

- One idea is that "The proof-theoretic ordinal of $\mathsf{PA}$ is $\le\epsilon_0$" means "$\mathsf{PRA}$ + an induction scheme along a natural notation for $\epsilon_0$ proves $Con(\mathsf{PA})$." So analogously we would ask how much induction we need to prove the consistency of true arithmetic. However, the above relies on the expressibility of $Con(\mathsf{PA})$ in the first place. Since per Tarski true arithmetic isn't even definable, we can't even set up the relevant question here.
- On the other hand, we could just ask something like: "Which ordinal notations does our theory prove the $\Sigma_1$ induction scheme for?" Here Tarski poses no barrier, but the answer trivializes in a different way. True arithmetic proves induction along all computable well-orders! So by this account the proof-theoretic ordinal of true arithmetic would just be $\omega_1^{CK}$.

So there is no real way to make sense of "the proof-theoretic ordinal of true arithmetic." Any notion of proof-theoretic ordinal relies on the theory in question being reasonably simple, which true arithmetic isn't.

Comment: Can we ask what arithmetically definable well-orderings does ACA_0 + the omega rule prove are well-founded, not in the sense of no Sigma_1 descending chains but in the sense of no descending chains period, using quantification over sets?

Comment: Alternatively, what if we add a unary predicate P(x) to the language of arithmetic, and then ask what arithmetically definable well-orderings R does PA with this predicate added + the omega-rule proves induction on P with respect to the ordering R?

Comment: To be clear, my first question wasn’t about ACA_0, it was about ACA_0 + the omega rule.  In any case, I think the answer to both my first question and my second question should be the same, and that the answer should be something between epsilon_0 and Gamma_0, much less than omega_1^CK.  Because Feferman and Schutte started with ACA_0 as a base theory, added the omega rule, and then added various ramified comprehension schemata, and obtained something that could only prove the well-foundedness of ordinals less than Gamma_0.  So just ACA_0 + the omega rule should be even weaker than that.

Comment: See pages 17-19 (according to the internal page numbering) of this Feferman paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2269764

Comment: Did you delete your comment?  By the way, I hope I’ve made clear why I think ACA_0 + the omega rule is relevant.  It’s because PA + the omega rule = true arithmetic, so ACA_0 + the omega rule should have basically the same strength.

Comment: If the omega rule gives you pause, what about just true arithmetic + ACA_0?  If you can prove that for every computable ordinal alpha, there exists an arithmetically definable well-ordering R of order type alpha such that true arithmetic + ACA_0 proves that there are no infinite descending chains with respect to R (expressed using quantification over sets), that would resolve my question.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/437103/5017